# Stripping off data from a file

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I have a file, which distributes data(numbers) into [(this is a screenshot of the original data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKVI8.png)8 columns, I have managed to write python code to take all this and arrange all of it into a single column and dump it into a text file. The file contains 30,000 data points, and I need to strip off some data (e.g, i want to take data only from data points 1400 to 8000) and then dump it into a text file. I'm seriously confused about this. Any pointers on where to start?

This is the code i wrote for putting it into one column.

```
file = open("C://Users//Randall//Desktop//randallseismic//Deep//Nakasen//EW1//AKTH170807240026.EW1", 'r')

scaled_values_file = open("scaled_values.txt", 'w')

scaled_factor = float(raw_input())

for line in file:        
    P = line.split()
    #print(P)
    P[-1] = P[-1].strip()
    for i in range(0,len(P)):
        #print(P[i])
        x = float(P[i]) * scaled_factor
        #print(x)
        y = str(x)
        scaled_values_file.write(y + "\n")

file.close()
scaled_values_file.close()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Perharps you could provide us some sample of your data. A first guess would be that using `pandas` could be a good solution

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.  You just want to write out only some of the lines...like skip the first 1399 rows, and then start writing, and stop after line 8000?  That seems like what you're saying, but that's so simple a thing to implement, that I bet I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  Here is how I would do it.  I would not worry about reading the file line by line (personal choice for small files) and I would open the files (both the reading and writing files) using "with" so each file gets automatically closed.

You want to extract just the data between points 1400 and 8000, and you have eight points per line, so you can define what rows you want to keep from the source file:

```
# convert to integer since Python does not like to slice using floats
firstRow = int(1400 / 8 - 1)
lastRow = int(8000 / 8 + 1)

scaled_factor = float(raw_input())

srcFile = "C://Users//Randall//Desktop//randallseismic//Deep//Nakasen/EW1//AKTH170807240026.EW1"

dstFile = "scaled_values.txt"

with open(srcFile, "w") as file:
    # read file, split by end of line character...then grab rows of interest
    data = file.read().split("\n")[firstRow:lastRow]

# now, convert your list of rows in "data" to an array and change type
data = np.array([r.split() for r in data], dtype=float)

# flatten array to 1d and apply scaling factor
data = data.flatten() * scaled_factor


# write data to file
with open(dstFile, "w") as fid:
    for dataPoint in data:
        fid.write(str(dataPoint) + "\n")
```